# C++ Equivalent of Java Character Class Fields

Tags: java, c++, unicode

I have a function in Java that needs to be rewritten in C++ that returns true if a given character fits into one of several punctuation categories. For example:

```
public static boolean isTargetPunctuationType(char a) {
    int type = Character.getType(a);
    return type == Character.COMBINING_SPACE_MARK ||
           type == Character.END_PUNCTUATION ||
           type == Character.INITIAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION || ...
}
```

The specific Character types are not important, but I want to know if an equivalent C++ class exists to categorize Unicode characters into different types the same way Java does via its Character class.

Comment: Since C++ didn't really have native Unicode characters until fairly recently, the support for such characters is woefully inadequate from a language- or standard library-standpoint. There are third-party libraries one can use though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If you already know about those libraries; why didnt you name one or two?

Comment: The open source ICU library is the home of this .